# Hi, i'm retrieving data from firestore, and checking whether to direct the user to index page or to enter details for a new user But not able to do so

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**React code**

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { auth, db } from "../firebase-config";
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    
    function Load() {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
    
      const [accountList, setAccountList] = useState([]);
      const [hasEmail, setHasEmail] = useState(false);
      const accountRef = collection(db, "accounts");
```

**Am i using useEffect correctly?**

```
      useEffect(() => {
        const getAccounts = async () => {
          const data = await getDocs(accountRef);
          setAccountList(
            data.docs.map((doc) => ({
              ...doc.data(),
              id: doc.id,
            }))
          );
        };
        getAccounts();
        emailCheck();
        direct();
      }, []);
```

**checking whether email exists**

```
      const emailCheck = () => {
        if (accountList.filter((e) => e.email === auth.currentUser.email)) {
          setHasEmail(true);
        } else {
          setHasEmail(false);
        }
      };
```

**Redirecting based on current user**

```
      const direct = () => {
        if (hasEmail) {
          navigate("/index");
        } else {
          navigate("/enterdetails");
        }
      };
      return <div></div>;
    }
```

The code compiles but doesn't redirect properly to any of the pages.
What changes should I make?
First question posted excuse me if format is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getAccounts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(accountRef);
    setAccountList(
      data.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }))
    );
  };
  getAccounts();
  emailCheck();
  direct();
}, []);
```

In order:

1. Since `getAccounts` is asynchronous, you need to use `await` when calling it.
2. But even then, [setting state is an asynchronous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) too, so the account list won't be updated immediately after `getAccounts` completes - even when you use `await` when calling it.

---

If you don't use the `accountList` for rendering UI, you should probably get rid of it as a `useState` hook altogether, and just use regular JavaScript variables to pass the value around.

But even if you use it in the UI, you'll need to use different logic to check its results. For example, you could run the extra checks inside the `getAccounts` function and have them use the same results as a regular variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getAccounts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(accountRef);
    const result = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));
    setAccountList(result);
    emailCheck(result);
    direct();
  };
  getAccounts();
}, []);

const emailCheck = (accounts) => {
  setHasEmail(accounts.some((e) => e.email === auth.currentUser.email));
};
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a second effect that depends on the `accountList` state variable to perform the check and redirect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getAccounts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(accountRef);
    setAccountList(
      data.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }))
    );
  };
  getAccounts();
});
useEffect(() => {
  emailCheck();
  direct();
}, [accountList]);
```

Now the second effect will be triggered each time the `accountList` is updated in the state.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the first solution but the following error occurs "Unexpected reserved word "await"". do async and await have to be used in pairs?

Comment: You can only use `await` in an `async` context indeed. I updated the first example in my answer.